# Constraint layout programmatically not using all assigned space (not filling width)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

in creating form-alike screen dynamically for what im using constraint layout. The problem is it is not taking all the space it's supposed to.

That's how it looks like.

[image]

Views are connected to the left as it appears (or to the screen if there is not any element to connect to)

Im expecting Spinners to take whole width and field "Nr Mieszkania" all the width that is left.

Here is function i use to create all the views and set constraint between them.

```
private fun generateLayout(filledForm: FilledForm, formFieldsData: ArrayList<FilledFormFieldData>, texts: ArrayList<EditText>) {
    val formFields = decodeForm(filledForm)   //decode from JSON to get info about type of fields, id etc
    val constraintLayout: ConstraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout)
    val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
    val views: ArrayList<View> = ArrayList()
    var formFieldsCounter: Int = 0

    //parsing decoded field to views and assign some basic attributes
    formFields.forEach {
        val layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(0, WRAP_CONTENT)
        formFieldsData.add(FilledFormFieldData(id = it.id, name = it.fieldName, type = it.type))
        var view: View? = null
        view?.layoutParams = layoutParams
        when (it.type) {
            "textField" -> {
                view = EditText(this)
                view.hint = it.fieldName
                texts.add(view)
            }
            "checkBox" -> {
                view = CheckBox(this)
                view.text = it.fieldName
            }
            "dictionaryTextField" -> {
                view = Spinner(this)
                val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayOf("Temporary", "Mocked", "Data"))
                view.adapter = arrayAdapter

            }
        }
        view!!.id = it.id!!
        view.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        views.add(view)
        constraintLayout.addView(view)
    }

    //set constraints (0 is parent(screen))
    constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout)
    views.forEach {
        constraintSet.constrainDefaultWidth(it.id, ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT_SPREAD)
        //TOP CONSTRAINT
        if (formFields[formFieldsCounter].layout_constraintTop_toSBottmOf == 0)
            constraintSet.connect(
                it.id,
                ConstraintSet.TOP,
                R.id.applicationNumberTextView,
                ConstraintSet.BOTTOM
            )
        else if (formFields[formFieldsCounter].layout_constraintTop_toSBottmOf != null)
            constraintSet.connect(
                it.id,
                ConstraintSet.TOP,
                formFields[formFieldsCounter].layout_constraintTop_toSBottmOf!!,
                ConstraintSet.BOTTOM
            )
        //BOTTOM CONSTRAINT
        if (formFields[formFieldsCounter].layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf == 0)
            constraintSet.connect(
                it.id,
                ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
                ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
                ConstraintSet.TOP
            )
        else if (formFields[formFieldsCounter].layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf != null)
            constraintSet.connect(
                it.id,
                ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
                formFields[formFieldsCounter].layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf!!,
                ConstraintSet.TOP
            )
        //LEFT CONSTRAINT
        if (formFields[formFieldsCounter].layout_constraintStart_toSEndOf == 0)
            constraintSet.connect(
                it.id,
                ConstraintSet.LEFT,
                ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
                ConstraintSet.LEFT
            )
        else if (formFields[formFieldsCounter].layout_constraintStart_toSEndOf != null)
            constraintSet.connect(
                it.id,
                ConstraintSet.LEFT,
                formFields[formFieldsCounter].layout_constraintStart_toSEndOf!!,
                ConstraintSet.RIGHT
            )
        //RIGHT CONSTRAINT
        if (formFields[formFieldsCounter].layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf == 0)
            constraintSet.connect(
                it.id,
                ConstraintSet.RIGHT,
                ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
                ConstraintSet.RIGHT
            )
        else if (formFields[formFieldsCounter].layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf != null)
            constraintSet.connect(
                it.id,
                ConstraintSet.RIGHT,
                formFields[formFieldsCounter].layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf!!,
                ConstraintSet.LEFT
            )
        formFieldsCounter++
    }
    constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout)
}
```

Im kinda stuck here thanks for any help :)

EDIT:
Adding my FormField data class (RealmObject is just extension that is needed to use Realm db.

```
open class FormField(

    @PrimaryKey
    var id: Int? = null,
    var fieldName: String? = null,
    var type: String? = null,
    var isRequired: Boolean? = null,
    var visibility: String? = null,
    var fontSize: String? = null,
    var fontColor: String? = null,
    var width: String? = null,
    var height: String? = null,
    var layout_constraintStart_toSEndOf: Int? = null,
    var layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf: Int? = null,
    var layout_constraintTop_toSBottmOf: Int? = null,
    var layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf: Int? = null,
    var widthdpp: Int? = null,
    var heightdpp: Int? = null,
    var layout_constraintStart_toSEndOfdpp: Int? = null,
    var layout_constraintEnd_toStartOfdpp: Int? = null,
    var layout_constraintTop_toSBottmOfdpp: Int? = null,
    var layout_constraintBottom_toTopOfdpp: Int? = null,
    var dictionary: Int? = null,
    var level: Int? = null,
    var regex: String? = null
): RealmObject()
```

Comment: Did you try `val layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT)`  on line after `formFields.forEach {`?

Comment: You mean change 0 to MATCH_PARENT ? Ain't working. Also 0 might be needed since that's how you make it match constraint ( at least that's what i know ). Thanks for trying tho :)

Comment: Seems like you are using the same layout params for text field, dictonaytext field and checkboz. If using 0 for width is required, you can get match parent behavior by constraining the left and right edges of a view to parent, just like how you would do in xml. What are you trying do with the else if blocks on LEFT and RIGHT constraints?

Comment: So its done this way:
In formFields that im decoding from JSON i hold data about fields. I ll edit post and add this data class for better understanding. Some of its attributes describe constraint connections(one for each side). First IF block describes what to do if this attribute is 0 (connect to parent->edge of the screen). ELSE IF block describes what to do if it connects something that is not 0(screen) and its not null so basically it connects some other view.

Comment: "formFields[formFieldsCounter].layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf!!" means ex. 3rd (depends on formFieldCounter) view's bottom constraint as id. By default im connecting bottom to TOP becouse the only situation when i want to constraint bottom to bottom is when i connect constraint to the screen, but its done in the 1st IF.

Comment: I did not get most of what you are trying to do here, but I had done something similar a while ago and you have to also set ids of the views generated by calling `generateViewId()` before accessing the id to use constraint on that. So something like `view.id = genearteViewId()` after `view.hint = it.fieldName`

Comment: Yeah i know about id's. Im setting them right after my " when (it.type) {...}".
Im using pre given ids "view!!.id = it.id!!" that i get from JSON file that i received before. You can see it in my FormField class

Comment: Also I prefer using `ConstraintSet.START` and `ConstraintSet.END` over their left and right counterpart

Comment: Are you sure that the id from FormField class is not null, as it is declared nullable there. I tried giving my views my own id, which is essentially similar to what you are doing. That did not work, I ended up using `viewToAdd.id = generateViewId()` before `holder.addView(viewToAdd)` ; your holder is `constraintLayout` and then `constraintSet.connect(viewToAdd.id, ConstraintSet.START, PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START)` ; so that `viewToAdd.id` is a valid id reference as we called `generateViewId()`

Comment: The thing is all the constraints are working fine and layout is generated properly ( i got alot other layout combinations for testing). Its just that its not filling empty space like there was maxEms or something. But what you are saying is for sure safer and i ll probably implement it that way. It was just easier to do since i could refer to id that was know (not some random generated id). Also it's declared null becouse that is Realm db requirement. If it was NULL then my IF statement wouldn't do anything with it and it wouldn't look lke that(everything would go to the left).

Comment: You said "That did not work". What was your outcome. Was it something like my issue or it was just not working ?

Comment: Cannot remember the precise nature of it, was some long time ago. Good luck though!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to use Your function and see where exactly is the problem but maybe it will help You. I created an XML sample layout that looks like Your wanted layout, so You can check if You set every param as I set in the layout.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Adres"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Nr Domu"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Nr mieszkania"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what im expecting to happen and what i actually do. I tried doing same thing just using pre-created listOf EditTexts in another - empty project and it worked. That might be some issue with doing it in function or something. Also in your XML first 2 should have android:layout_width="0dp" aswell. That's how im doing it. Its walk in the park while doing it in XML but for some reason it doensn't work like that when i create it programmatiaclly. Maybe that's becouse of some "hidden" attributes that EditText has when you create it like ems etc. Will take a closer look at it.

Comment: What do You mean by `Also in your XML first 2 should have android:layout_width="0dp"`? Two editTexts in Constraint Layout?

Comment: You created 3 EditText here. First 2 of them have             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

and the 3rd has 
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: Just saying all of them should have android:layout_width="0dp" so it works perfectly.
You never know which one will be the last. But for this example it is irrelevant.